how to filter huge csv file by pandas
I have a 10GB csv file data/history_{date_to_be_searched}.csv. it has more than 27000 zip codes. On the basis of zip code I have to filter the csv file then each filtered file I have to upload to azure blob storage.
I am taking data in chunks of size 1 000 000 like this for chunk in pd.read_csv(f'data/history_{date_to_be_searched}.csv', chunksize=1000000): and then taking the unique zipcode from chunk uniquezipcode = df_final["zipcode"].unique() then uploading it to blob storage.
In this way chuck is looping 25 times and data filter is looping 27 000 times. This is taking too much time around 70 hours. so I thought to use map() insted of looping like this.
def filtered_data():
    try:
        for chunk in pd.read_csv(f'data/history_{date_to_be_searched}.csv', chunksize=1000000):
            df_final=chunk
            uniquezipcode = df_final["zipcode"].unique()
            grouped_data = df_final.groupby('zipcode')
            del df_final
            data_for_upload = [(zipcode, group_df) for zipcode, group_df in grouped_data]
            map(upload_filtered_data,*zip(*data_for_upload))
            del data_for_upload

    except Exception as e:
        print("filtered_data Error : ",e)
          
def upload_filtered_data(each_zone,df_filter):
    global date_to_be_searched
    try:
         if df_filter.shape[0] != 0:
            file_path = f"{path}/{container_name}/{date_to_be_searched.year}/{date_to_be_searched.month}/{each_zone}/{each_zone}{date_to_be_searched}.parquet"
            outdir = f"{path}/{container_name}/{date_to_be_searched.year}/{date_to_be_searched.month}/{each_zone}/"
            outdir_blob = f"{date_to_be_searched.year}/{date_to_be_searched.month}/{each_zone}/{each_zone}{date_to_be_searched}.parquet"
            fullname = os.path.join(outdir, f"{each_zone}{date_to_be_searched}.parquet")
            if not os.path.exists(file_path):
                os.makedirs(file_path)
            else:
                df_filter = merge_df(df_filter, file_path)
                df_filter.to_parquet(fullname, allow_truncated_timestamps=True)
            upload_to_blob(fullname, outdir_blob)
            del each_battery
            del df_filter
          
    except Exception as e:
        print("upload_filtered_data Error : ",e)

I think this way will be much faster but it take RAM due to which every time I run this script is getting terminated/killed. please suggest any other efficient way or should I reduce chunk size? Are there any ways to filter the whole csv file in single loop without loading in RAM?

If I understand you right, at the end you will have to send 27000 files to blob storage (each file one zip)?

yes right if in next chunk same zipcode comes again then it will merge it with previous file then upload it again. @AndrejKesely

Perhaps it would help if you posted a sample of the CSV file and an example of the desired result. Since you have a CSV file it should be trivial to import it to a SQLite DB, then you can perform SQL operations such as select distinct, group by etc. I have the impression that map, zip are wasteful but I can´t visualize your data.

Have a look at the iterator to consume the file.

It is not clear which part is supposed to take RAM or be slow in the current code. Moreover, we cannot run/test it nor have any idea of what the CSV look like in practice. I do not understand how the computing part can take 70h to execute so I expect the upload to be slow... However, if this is the case, then there is not much things to do apart from reducing the amount of data sent (removing duplicates + data compression). Besides note that uniquezipcode is computed but unused and that groupby already compute unique items.

If you just want to group the dataframe by zipcode but it is too big to be done at once, you can 1. use a machine with more RAM (simplistic naive solution), or 2. write this yourself by using an efficient compact hash-table and appending lines to 27000 files iteratively (possibly using caches so to reduce the number of IO requests). At the end you can sent the files once for all. Some SQL engine may help to do that relatively-efficiently indeed (at least it should not take 70h on a mainstream system).

actually that 10GB csv file is just one day data which I fetched from citus(azure postgres distributed DB) I can't fetch the entire day data at once so i am fetching it for 30 mins interval so total 48 loops for data fetching from 00:00:00 to 11:59:59 of that day. could you please explain more on your point 2. also FYI one simple select query for one zipcode takes 9-12 mins due to large no. of request to database.@JérômeRichard

I ran into similar problems once. In my case it was due to large lists.
I found out by using tracemalloc to locate memory leaks
In your case iterating over grouped_data is likely to produce many pd.DataFrames which can be very expensive.
Have you tried to use dict or OrderedDict instead of lists or DataFrames?
dicts are much faster than lists with many items and are created much faster than DataFrames.
With enough memory you could accumulate only the data you really need in a dict with zipcode as key which makes them truely unique (if you can manage to run over the whole csv)
